# Cmnd-Tab to new Finder window if no window is open

Tags: macos, osx-lion, finder

If I cmnd+tab to Finder and no Finder window is open, then it follows that ***100% of the time*** my next action is going to be cmnd+n to make a new window. Is there a hack to make this automatically happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold option before releasing command, the application switcher will reopen that application. (Or unminimize a window or create a new default window if it has no unminimized windows.)

[LiteSwitch X](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8242/liteswitch-x) has an option to make that behavior the default.

[image: LiteSwitch]

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) has a similar feature, relaunching Finder when no windows are open.

[image: Witch Window]

Comment: You are a golden tear from the eye of Horus. Thank you. From the bottom of my soul.

Comment: Added Witch to your answer if you don't mind /cc @ninjatyler

Comment: Lite Switch X looks to be out of commission. You can download it, but the link to buy is dead.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>How about always cmd+n? If a finder exists you will be taken to it. Otherwise a finder is opened.</strike>

My memory fades faster every day. Instead of cmd+tab, click on the Finder in the Dock. If none exists, a new one will be created. Else you'll be moved to the desktop with the existing one. If you have more than one open, you'll be moved to the last one used.

Comment: What do you mean? The OP wants to `Cmd-Tab` to Finder and automatically open a window.

Comment: cmd+tab on the empty desktop (which is equivalent to the finder) shows the active apps, and within this there may be an active finder window. cmd-n on the empty desktop switches to the active finder window, if there is none, a new window is created.

Comment: *> cmd-n on the empty desktop switches to the active finder window* – that is not true. It will always create a new Finder window. The OP however wanted a solution for a situation where there's *no* window anyway, so I think you don't understand the problem.

Comment: I can't try this again before Saturday. I'll be back.

Comment: @slhck I've modified my reply.